# Infinite scrolling in React Native using Flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, infinite-scroll, react-native-flatlist

I'm fetching data from API which limits 20 items per page. I'm trying to implement scrolling so when I reach the end of the 20 items, a new page with additional 20 items is retrieved and displayed but I also want to keep all previous items and make it available when I scroll back to the top, and this is where I'm failing.

This is what I'm doing by steps.

1. I'm rendering the screen
2. the useEffect is triggered and I fetch the first page of the API
3. first batch of 20 items is then rendered using a Flatlist
4. when I scroll to the end, I call a function [loadMoreCommit] which increases the [page] by 1
5. the useEffect is triggered again since has a dependency on [page] and fetches the following batch of 20 items and so on...

All working as expected so far except for the fact that I only see 20 items at the time and losing all previous ones.

```
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const loadMoreCommit = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/popular?api_key=${ENV.tmdbApiKey}&page=${page}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.results);        
      });
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [page]);

return (
          <FlatList            
            data={data}
            initialNumToRender={10}            
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            onEndReached={loadMoreCommit}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            renderItem={(itemData) => (
              <StarsItem
                id={itemData.item.id}
                count={count++}
                backdrop={itemData.item.profile_path}
                poster={itemData.item.profile_path}
                title={itemData.item.name}
              />
            )}
          />
)
```

Reading other posts, I tried to keep historical data by replacing

```
setData(res.results);
```

If I use

```
setData({ data: [...data, ...res.results] });
```

I get *"Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"* warning

I also tried to concatenate previous and new values which works on some tutorials but I get an error

```
setData({ data: data.concat(res.results) });
```

*data.concat is not a function*

Comment: try setData([...data, ...res.results]);

Comment: It works, thanks so much, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better option would be `setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...res.results])`.